# topic upvote count stays the same if vote is abrogated

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-badges

I had a positive vote in the c# tag badge category which raised my category up vote count.  The up vote was undone but I still had it in my up vote count in the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag score statistics are cached daily (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/topusers) see bottom of the page.

It is too expensive to calculate these puppies on the fly (same cache is used in the tag wiki page - and hopefully in the user page some day)

Comment: There's another issue going on though, the question/answer votes themselves (the denormalized versions) *aren't* being updated correctly in all cases, a vote later *usually* fixes it which makes me think deadlock/rollback issue still...are you guys aware of that lingering issue?

Answer (score 1):

The data is cached to avoid the expensive of hitting the dbase frequently.  It will take some time for the cache to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wacky going on with vote denormalization, this is definitely a bug at the moment.  I assume it's still a remnant deadlock issue where the normalized vote total update gets rolled back...but whatever the cause I'm seeing it a dozen time a day as well.